# How to detect shift in static camera?

Tags: opencv, camera, emgucv, shift

I'm looking for help in solving my problem. I have a static camera, which is focus on one place. I download current view at every 1 second.

I would like to write a program which detects when someone moves the camera in a different direction. After that I would like to generate image with the shift. I am currently come up with this solution:

1. Create a base frame, to which I compare all future frames.
2. Generate edge with Canny Edge algorithm.
3. Then I generate the corner points with Harris algorithm.
4. Then I want to compare the current frame with a base frame (picture, where are just corner points on black background) with calcOpticalFlowPyrLK (Lucas-Kanade method).

Unfortunately I have problems, because depending on the lighting, the number of people, etc., the edges and corners are change. Because of this I don't know if there was a shift or not.

Can somebody give me some advices any solution how to detect shift?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

See the opencv's standard example:

opencv/samples/cpp/phase_corr.cpp

I think it is that you are looking for.

Comment: So far, so good :)
I'm still trying to read more about phase correlation, but it's working :)